# how to change chart border corner to rounded shape and to change color of excel sheet background after removing gridline

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I've made chart using xlsxwriter and want to change its border corner to rounded shape. chart is look like as mentioned in picture.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cM8co.png]

I want output chart like this
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQ4Qy.png]

Furthermore, after removing the gridlines i want to change the background color of excel sheet.

Comment: Changing to rounded corners isn't supported in XlsxWriter. If you want to change the background of the worksheet you will have to change the cell format for all the cells in the worksheet (afaik). You would do that with `set_column()`. If you want to set the background of the chart then take a look at the chart `set_plotarea()` and `set_chartarea()` methods.

Comment: thanks for your help..but is there any other solution for corner because i have more the 48 graphs to make them manually..in openpyxl or any other?